# What is the equivalent of Selenium IDE's setTimeout and setSpeed in Selenium WebDriver using Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

What would be the Python Selenium WebDriver equivalent for setTimeout and setSpeed? I have following Selenium IDE code which returns an error when exported to Python/unittest/Webdriver code:

```
<tr>
       <td>setTimeout</td>
       <td>60000</td>
       <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <td>setSpeed</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td></td>
</tr>
```

Exported Python/unittest/WebDriver code is as below:

```
 def test_sam(self):
        driver = self.driver
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [setTimeout]]
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [setSpeed]]
        .....
```

The same IDE code works for RC but not for WebDriver. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly then I think the equivalent for setSpeed would be

```
driver = Driver()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # The time that webdriver will wait for actions to happen before failing
```

Something equivalent to set speed I have not come across. You can try removing it and seeing if you encounter any failures. In my experience all you need is the implicit wait.

See this page for full docs: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

Comment: so I want to make changes in my python script whichever not supported items in default rite?

Comment: Yup, you just need to actually change your Python script.

Comment: What about something decoupled from grabing items. I have a table that gets populated, but sometimes it doesn't have all the info yet and I can't tell exactly how many items it should be in there. So I grab the table and sometimes it is empty or half loaded. so I need something that does not depend on whatever I'm grabing. But just a simple wait.

Comment: In Python that would be time.sleep(10)

Answer (score 1):

Implicit waits let you write sloppy code; use WebDriverWait and actually understand your application's synchronization needs.

As for what timeouts are available to you, Se is open source so looking at the code reveals

```
Adam-Gouchers-MacBook:remote adam$ grep def webdriver.py | grep time_to_wait
    def implicitly_wait(self, time_to_wait):
    def set_script_timeout(self, time_to_wait):
    def set_page_load_timeout(self, time_to_wait):
```

Each method even has an explanation if you need to understand them further.

Comment: Yes, It's better to use Explicit wait rather than Implicit wait.

Comment: the issue is that for some reason the item is present but when I try to get the html it is not the expected result, maybe due to some extra adding going on. So after the id is present I want to wait some extra safe time to get the whole content. It is not like I know how many items will be inserted.